# Link Button, Como desactivar asp:LinkButton despues del primer clic? para evitar el doble clic

Tags: javascript, c#, asp, webforms, aspx

Estoy intentando evitar un doble clic, es decir, al primer clic poder deshabilitar el "LinkButton" pero por medio de funciones javascript, todo esto es en una pagina "aspx".

Tengo poca experiencia en front end, si me pueden apoyar se los agradecere.

he intentado justamente utilizando: setAttribute, getElementById, attr.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function disabledLinkBringDataFlow() {
           
            document.getElementById('btnBringDataFlow').setAttribute("disabled", "");
           
            //document.getElementById("btnBringDataFlow").disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBringDataFlow" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Cancel" OnClick="btnBringDataFlow_Click" OnClientClick="disabledLinkBringDataFlow()">Bring Data</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ToolTip="Cancel" >Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image: error al ejecutar la funcion javascript en el documento aspx]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disabledLinkBringDataFlow() {

        document.getElementById('btnBringDataFlow').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias ver de acceder directo al boton pasando su instancia por parametro

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnBringDataFlow" runat="server" ... OnClientClick="disabledLinkBringDataFlow(this)">Bring Data</asp:LinkButton>
```

Entonces en el javascript quedaria

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disabledLinkBringDataFlow(ctrl) {
        ctrl.disabled= true;
    }
</script>
```

[How to disable Submit button after click using JavaScript](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/disable-submit-button-after-first-click-using-javascript.htm)

Answer (score 0):

estuve realizando varias investigaciones y resulta algo extraño, ya que sus respuestas son funcionales pero en este caso no las reconocía el DOM, las pasaba de largo, intente varias maneras como las que mencioné en el comentario de esta publicación, en fin la respuesta quedo de esta manera.

```js
 <script>
     function preventDoubleClick() {
       $("#" + '<%= btnBringDataFlow.ClientID %>').addClass("disabled");
        $("#" + '<%= btnBringDataFlow.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
 </script>
```

El "btnBringDataFlow" es el Id de mi "asp:LinkButton".